# Zend router, omit controller in URL for single module

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I have a module based Zend application.

One of my modules, called `portfolio` has only one controller, called `index`. For this single module, I'd like my route to look like this:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('portfolio/:action',
                                          array(
                                                'module'        => 'portfolio',
                                                'controller'    => 'index',
                                                'action'        => 'index'
                                               )
                                         );
```

This works but messes up all links generated through `Zend_Navigation`.

Can this routing behavior be achieved, without messing up `Zend_Navigation`? (i.e. only inbound links are routed through this route. Outbound links are generated with the default route)

I can't use `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Can you try setting up the reverse route pattern?

Comment: Did you add the routes in your navigation pages? Use `<route>default</route>` for default routes.